# Is there any functional difference between c# sealed and Java's final keyword?

Tags: c#, java, final, sealed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the equivalent of Java’s final in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327544/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javas-final-in-c)

In Java final applies to more than just a class.

So, I wonder: is there any functional difference between the two keywords?

Thank you, and sorry for a relatively noob question.

A quick Google search did not satisfy my needs.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327544/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javas-final-in-c

Comment: why don't you simply compare the documentation?

Comment: RTFM, huh. Well, Let's close this Q peacefully. Thank you all! I had to chose one answer as accepted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Java's `final` keyword is the equivalent of C#'s `sealed`, `readonly`, and `sealed` keywords.

Two of those three are somewhat different in Java and C#:

In Java, methods are virtual by default, so any method can be declared `final` to prevent it from being overriden.  In C#, methods are not virtual by default, so the only overridden methods can be declared `sealed`  (To prevent them from being further overridden)

In Java, any variable or field can be declared `final` to prevent it from being changed after initialization  (And, for fields, outside the constructor).  In C#, fields can be declared `readonly`, for the exact same effect, but local variables cannot.  Note that Java has no equivalent of C#'s `const` keyword.  (`const`s in C# are evaluated at compile-time, and the values are hard-coded instead of being referenced)

For classes, C#'s `sealed` classes and Java's `final` classes are exactly the same (AFAIK).

Comment: @Matthew: That was not a typo.  C# has two different uses of the `sealed` keyword.  In VB, they are `NotInheritable` and `NotOverridable`

Comment: I find the answer somewhat confusing, which is why I thought it was a typo.  `sealed` is one keyword with multiple contextual meanings (like many keywords, including `final`, `default`, `using`, etc.).  C# `const` is used many places where Java would use `static final`; thus, I think it should be listed atop as one of the equivalents.

Comment: @Matthew: **No**.  `const` in C# is _not_ equivalent to `static final`.

Comment: I am aware there is not a 1 to 1 mapping (final is also used in the other ways you listed), which is why I said "many places".  But if you have a Java constant like `private static final int MY_NUMBER = 3` (which is of course quite frequent), I believe `private const int MY_NUMBER = 0;` is the best mapping to C#; of course, you can not use static with C# constants.  So `const` is the closest equivalent to *some* uses of `static final`.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look into this answer: [What is the equivalent of Java’s final in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327544/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javas-final-in-c/1327549#1327549)