# C# sealed vs Java final

Tags: c#, java, sealed

Would anybody please tell me as the reason the following use of `sealed` does not compile? Whereas, if I replace `sealed` with `final` and compile it as Java, it works.

```csharp
private sealed int compInt = 100;
public bool check(int someInt)
{
    if (someInt > compInt)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069010/is-there-any-functional-difference-between-c-sharp-sealed-and-javas-final-keywo

Comment: The equivalent to `final` for members in C# is `readonly`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

That's because `final` in Java means plenty of different things depending on where you use it whereas `sealed` in C# applies *only* to classes and inherited virtual members (methods, properties, events).

In Java `final` can be applied to:

- **classes**, which means that the class cannot be inherited. This is the equivalent of C#'s `sealed`.
- **methods**, which means that the method cannot be overridden in a derived class. This is the default in C#, unless you declare a method as `virtual` and in a derived class this can be prevented for further derived classes with `sealed` again. That's why you see `sealed` members in C# a lot less than `final` members in Java.
- **fields** and **variables**, which means that they can only be initialized once. For fields the equivalent in C# is `readonly`.

Comment: "sealed in C# applies only to classes" - it is not true, it can be applied to methods in C#.

Comment: readonly fields can be modified in the constructor (just a small difference with Java's final)

Answer (score 7):

`Sealed` in `C#` can be applied only to a *reference types*, and has impact on *inheritance tree*.

In practise the type marked as `sealed` guranteed to be the last "leaf" in the inheritance tree, or in short, you can not derive from the type declared like a `sealed`.

```
public sealed class Child : Base 
{
}

public class AnotherAgain : Child //THIS IS NOT ALLOWED
{
}
```

It can not be applied to a members.

Answer (score 2):

Tigran's answer is not wrong while Joey's is a little incorrect.
Firstly you can look into this page: [What is the equivalent of Java's final in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327544/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javas-final-in-c).

the `sealed` key word can apply to `class`,`instance method` and `property` but not variables, or interface's methods. Classes with `sealed` cannot be inherited. When `sealed` put on method， it must be by `override` in company. Every `struct` is `sealed`, so `struct` cannot be inherited. Check this image: [image: sealed usage]