# Make keyword "final" acceptable for C#?

Tags: java, c#

In a Java/Spring/C# project, I intend to have a list of returncodes which shall be available at both sides: Java and C#. First guess was to have a file which is available in both worlds and defines constants:

```
private static final int RC_NO_ERROR = 0;
```

Unfortunately, `final` is not known to C#, and the C# equivalents `const`, `sealed` and `readonly` are not known to Java. Is there any easy way like a preprocessor which helps with that? Can I "define" the keyword `final` to be at least tolerated if not recognized as `const` and friends?

My plan b woud be to let sed/awk do the job but I would prefer a solution which does not involve a tool chain step.

Comment: äh? what are you trying to do? are pasting code from java in VisualStudio?

Comment: There´s no pre-processor as you may know from C that allows you to replace any content within the source-code by some other content. But it´s quite unclaer *why* you even need this. Why do you switch between C# and Java all the time? Are you writing a multi-language app?

Comment: Try to read those answers [C# sealed vs Java final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170633/c-sharp-sealed-vs-java-final)

Comment: Probably in near future You will ask about more than const compatible in two language protocol Java/C##. Read about multi-language protocols builders like Thrift, Protobuf, (old SOAP too) and few more

Answer (score 0):

Just dont use "final" in Java?
Yes, then it is no constant, but since it is private, you can hold yourself back not to modify it later.