# Is it possible to extend a class with a default private constructor in Dart?

Tags: dart

Suppose that we have a `class a`:

```
class A {
  A._();
}
```

Its *default constructor* is *private*: `A._()`.

Is there any way to `extends` that class?

### Problem

```
class B extends A {

}
```

This results in a *compiler **error***:

```
The superclass 'A' doesn't have a zero argument constructor.
```

Trying to compose *any* constructor for `B` myself (`B()`) results in another error:

```
The superclass 'A' doesn't have an unnamed constructor.
```

Comment: If you write a constructor, the class does not get a default constructor (the implicit `A():super();` constructor that would be added otherwise). The `A._` constructor is not a "default constructor", nor is it an unnamed constructor. You can still add an unnamed constructor `A();` to the class as well.

Comment: @lrn *Default constructor* was the term I found for it. Usually it would be `A()`, but that gets removed once `A._()` is added. Thus `A` does neither have a *public* zero argument nor unnamed constructor. `A()` would be zero argument und unnamed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no way. This is an effective way to prevent extending.

What you still can do is implementing the class.

```
class B implements A {}
```

If the class *also* has a public non-factory constructor, you can still extend it by forwarding the constructor call to such a named constructor of the super class.

```
class B extends A {
  B() : super.other();
}
```

Comment: That is awful. What reason would there be to prevent extending? I noticed that implementing was possible, but that is not what I am looking for. Also, I will just adjust my question with *PascalCase*. I wrote those error messages myself. I did not really name classes *`a`* and *`b`*.

Comment: Most serious programming languages allow that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170633/c-sharp-sealed-vs-java-final. There are many things a class can't guarantee when it can be extended.

Comment: Extending would only add features, or am I wrong? If the class is not intended to be extended, there are no overrides necessary anyway and one could just add to the class what they want. I also do not understand why privacy is enforced by the compiler.  Ignoring it would be my own responsibility.

Comment: Extending can either add features or broke it. :) Depends on the implementations.

Comment: "Ignoring it would be my own responsibility". If a developer doesn't want his classes to be used in ways that would prevent them from working correctly, he should have the power. If this prevents you from using a package, then raise an issue to make the author aware. Not everyone wants a JavaScript-like world where everyone can do what he wants and then swamp the internet with complaints and bug reports and buggy code ;-)