# ArrayList: help to translate from Java to C#

Tags: c#, java, arraylist

How can I translate this Java code:

```
private List<MPoint> classes = new ArrayList<MPoint>(); // MPoint is my own class
```

to C#? And what does final keyword mean in Java? What analogue there is to it in C#?
I am newbie in C# and Java and I need help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private IList<MPoint> classes = new List<MPoint>();
```

`IList<T>` is an interface implemented by the generic collection class `List<T>`.

`final` has different meanings in Java depending on its context:

- `final` on a class or method is like `sealed` in C#
- `final` on a variable is like `readonly` in C#.

Equivalent of `final` in C# is discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327544/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javas-final-in-c).

Comment: But how similar are the implementations of C# List to Java ArrayList?  What's backing the interface?

Comment: @Snekse - that's a different question, which you could ask on the site if you really need an answer

Answer (score 4):

```
private IList<MPoint> classes = new List<MPoint>();
```

The Java `List` interface is analogous to the .NET [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) interface.
The `ArrayList` concrete type is is analogous to the .NET [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) type.

`final` is a bit more complicated. In *this* case (field declaration + initializer), the closest would be `readonly`. On the other hand, as of the current version, there's no way to mark a local variable as `final` in C#. (Off-topic, `final` in the context of compile-time constants = `const`. In the context of "cannot override / inherit further" = `sealed`).

EDIT: To answer your question about what "final" means, it is normally used to indicate a *kind* of immutability - that something cannot be further modified or overridden. What sort of mutability is *actually* prevented with that modifier and its C# analogues depends on context and is hard to describe without going into specifics.

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to what you've written.

```
List<MPoint> classes = new List<MPoint>();
```

Comment: and `final` in Java is `const` in C#

Answer (score 0):

Final in Java means that after the first assignment to a final variable you can not change it anymore. I am unsure what is the equivalent in C#.

The code is the same as AS-CII said but I would have written it like

```
private IList<MPoint> classes = new List<MPoint>();
```