# C# prevent base class method from being hidden by new modifier in the derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Here's my situation. In Java I can mark a method as final in the base/super class and there is no way a derived class can mask a method of the same signature. In C# however, the new keyword allows someone inheriting my class to create a method with the same signature.

See my example below. I need to keep the `orignal.MyClass` public so please don't suggest that as an answer. This seems to be a lost feature moving from Java to C#:

```cs
public class orignal.MyClass{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
     // Do something
    }
}

class fake.MyClass: orignal.MyClass {
    // How to prevent the following
    public new void MyMethod()
    {
     // Do something different
    }
}
```

EDIT: Not a duplicate.

All answers seem to suggest, it's not possible to prevent a method from being hidden/shadowed in a derived class. This became apparent while migrating some old Java code to C#. A final method in Java will not let anybody use the same method signature in any derived class. While it's great in most scenarios that C# allows a method of same signature in the derived class, it would have been great to prevent such a behavior if warranted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of Java's final in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327544/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javas-final-in-c) ...

Comment: As mentioned by @Reed, `it rarely matters`. Your code will still call the original method.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I am not asking for an equivalent. I am suggesting one doesn't exist for this use case.

Answer (score 12):

> // How to prevent the following

There is no way to prevent this.  It's allowed by the language.

Note that, in practice, this rarely matters.  If you expect your base class to be used *as your class*, your method will still be called.  Using `new` only hides the method when using the `DerivedClass` from a a variable declared as `DerivedClass`.

This means that your API, if built around `MyClass`, will always still call `MyMethod` when instances are passed into your methods.

---

Edit in response to comments:

If you are worried about people subclassing your class in general, the only real option you do have would be to seal your class:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
```

This will prevent people from creating a subclass entirely.  If you want to allow people to derive from your class, however, there is no way to prevent them from hiding your method in their class.

Comment: I made an edit. It is very easily possible for someone using my api (say Alice) to create a wrapper that has a class with the same name and then if this wrapper were to be used by another person, it will allow Alice to redefine the behavior of MyMethod() and possibly fool an unsuspecting end-developer

Comment: @JAson Not really - the developer would have to include the other person's namespace instead of yours, or fully qualify the type.  Either way, they'd have to know what they're doing.

Comment: @JAson that's _overriding_, not _hiding_.  Hiding a method has no impact to the base class.

Comment: @JAson The premise of your situation has someone running code from an untrusted malicious source.  When you're in that situation you've already lost.  Proper development is not putting yourself in that position to begin with.

Comment: @ReedCopsey You can mark a method as `sealed` in addition to a class to seal just that method, without sealing the whole class.  It can still be shadowed though, just not overridden.

Comment: @Reed/@Servy: Agreed in principle. However the lack of a modifier similar to what final does for a java method in a base class, results in a method of same signature to be created in a derived class. Again not trying to push this into a discussion on development ethics/properness, but it seems reasonable to expect a modifier that if present in a base class method prevents any one from overriding and hiding it.

Comment: @JAson Well, reasonable or not, that's the behavior, and it's not going to change (it would be too much of a breaking change to be implemented).  So there really isn't anything else to say.  Don't do it if it bothers you, and live with the fact that others can do it if *they* want to.

Comment: @Servy I edited to mention sealing the class just because of the comments - the method wasn't virtual, so sealing wouldn't work (and wouldn't change the behavior in terms of this question anyways)

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent a public method or property being masked, but why would you? It takes a deliberate action from whoever extends the base class to do this (i.e. they need to type `new`), so they have intended to do it, why try and stop them?

Maybe you need to switch your pattern up a bit? If the extender must use your base method then you can put something critical in it, thus forcing them to call it. Of course this is smelly if not done correctly, so if you use this approach then mark your method as `virtual`, then in the documentation (or method header comments) mention that the base method must be called. This way you avoid the extender having to hide/mask your method (although they still could), but they can still extend it if they want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to create interface the put your method definition within it, then let the original class to implement the interface and implement the method explicitly:

```
    interface IAnimal
    {
        string diary(string notes, int sleephours);   
    }

    class Dogs:IAnimal
    {        

virtual public string voice()
        {
            string v = "Hao Hao"; return v;
        } 
        string IAnimal.diary(string notes,int sleephours)
        {
            return notes + sleep.ToString() + " hours";
        }

    }

    class Cats:Dogs
    {
        public override string voice()
        {
            string v = "Miao Miao"; return v;
        }
    }
```

You will not use diary() method via Cats instance.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you really want to prevent someone from *overriding* the method - hiding a method with `new` cannot be prevented, but it poses no risk to the base class, so that shouldn't be an issue.

In C# methods are not overrideable by default.  So you can simply prevent someone form overriding a base method by not marking it `virtual` or `abstract`.   In Java methods are virtual by default, so sealing a method by using `final` is necessary to prevent overriding.

Comment: The question seems pretty clear that it is about the new keyword and not preventing overriding...

Comment: Note that in C# you can also mark a method as `sealed` which functions virtually identially to `final` in java.  You can actually seal a virtual method.  I.e. having a virtual method overwritten by a derived class, but having  it seal it to prevent further re-definitions.

Comment: @JAson You most certainly *can* seal a method in a base class.  You can absolutely prevent it from being overridden, but you can never prevent it from being shadowed using *new*, as everyone else has told you.  That's just fact.

Comment: @Jason - methods are sealed _by default_ unless you mark them as _virtual_ or _abstract_

Comment: @Servy/Stanley: Got it, you are right. whats different is that you can hide/shadow a sealed method with a new modifier which won't be possible in Javaland. Guess will have to live with it.

Answer (score -1):

For prevent of hiding base class method you can do like this:

```
public class Org
{
    public void Do()
    {
        // do something
    }
}

public class Fake : Org
{
    public new void Do()
    {
        base.Do();
        // do something
    }
}
```

here the base keyword refers to Father class.
now you called method from Father class (here is Org) in child class and now this method doesnt hide anymore.

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation of how your code solves OP's problem?

Comment: @Bender the Greatest I'm not so professional in C# but we can call this method and it is not hidding now . but please help me to understand what is the problem with using this way?

Comment: It's best to provide some sort of explanation in an answer to how the code fixes a problem presented in the question. Otherwise, the community generally sees code-only answers as "low quality" which can contribute to downvotes. In some cases, the answer could be deleted. The goal of SO is to not only help the asker, but future visitors.

Comment: This isn't an admonishment, but rather a tip for writing quality answers.

Comment: thank u for your complete answer. i will send better answers since now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31880214)