# Cannot access static constants from testing project

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

For my unit test, I'm trying to use constants from a static class (`ModelConstants`) of my main project in my testing project.

```
int ones = ModelConstants.PLOT_STORE_PRECISION_FACTOR * ModelConstants.RECENT_SAMPLES;
```

When trying to run this test method, I get a `TypeInitializationException` on the line above. InnerException is a `FileNotFoundException` saying the assembly `System.Windows` could not be found. This makes no sense to me, but I guess the static constants class could somehow not be initialized correctly. What could be the reason for this?

Btw, I can instantiate non-static classes of my main project without any problems.

***Edit:***

The constants are defined as follows:

```
public static readonly int TRACKING_INTERVAL = 200;
public static readonly int SAMPLE_WINDOW = 3;
public static readonly int PLOT_STORE_PRECISION_FACTOR = 1000 / TRACKING_INTERVAL;
```

Comment: Are those constants as in `const`? If so, I'd be very surprised that you could get a runtime exception here, because the compiler should compile that in.

Comment: please share the ModelConstants code snippet

Comment: Ok, added them. Could the problem be that one is dependent on another constant? They work just fine in my main code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static readonly int TRACKING_INTERVAL = 200;
public static readonly int SAMPLE_WINDOW = 3;
public static readonly int PLOT_STORE_PRECISION_FACTOR = 1000 / TRACKING_INTERVAL;
```

Those are not constants. These are class static fields. When such a field is being read, the static class constructor is invoked. There you have your `TypeInitializationException`, which throws on type initialization. The reason is in the `InnerException`.

Instead, I would recommended using constants:

```
public const int TRACKING_INTERVAL = 200;
public const int SAMPLE_WINDOW = 3;
public const int PLOT_STORE_PRECISION_FACTOR = 1000 / TRACKING_INTERVAL;
```

These are checked and accessed at compile time and may even increase performance.

Comment: Cool, changing `static readonly` to `const` (where possible) did the trick. The original reason I had used `readonly` was because I'm home in Java and searched for an alternative for `final static` and found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327544/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javas-final-in-c
:)

Comment: @CedricReichenbach - For what it's worth, if you want a "constant" class variable, you *have* to declare it as `static readonly` instead of `const`.  You can only use `const` for value types.

Answer (score 1):

From the data you presented, the only possible reason I see for the error is that the `ModelConstants` class has a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) which, for some reason, throws an exception in the test project only.

It could be that the constructor accesses some global state that is not initialized in the test project.

Comment: Never touch the static member of another type inside of a static constructor.